# Enabling Hyper-V for windows 8.1 hangs HP Pavilion g6-2245sx on boot-up

Tags: windows-phone-8, virtual, hyper-v

I want to activate windows phone8.1 emulator on visual studio 2013 on my HP Pavilion g6-2245sx Notebook.

I enabled virtual technology from bios then I [enabled the hyper-v feature](http://blogs.technet.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/440x0/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-48-12/4276.HVW8b.jpg)

When I reboot my notebook, I discovered that it hangs at the Windows logo screen [screenshot](http://s28.postimg.org/lrkhfhxyl/asdasdasd.jpg)

If I disable Hyper-V again, the notebook boots up.

Does anyone know why my notebook hangs at boot-up when I enable Hyper-V?

Answer (score 0):

If you're having a Win 8.1 Enterprise have a look in here:

https://superuser.com/questions/731643/

or else check out these fixes.

[Windows 8.1 hangs or freezes](http://winaero.com/blog/fix-windows-8-1-hangs-or-freezes/)